# MSBuild custom common targets

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild

I'm finishing setting up a TFS build definition and having problems with getting [MSBuild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild) to run any code that I've put in the `Custom.After.Microsoft.Common.Targets` file. The file is definitely in the right place, and is definitely being parsed (breaking the syntax in the file causes build errors), but none of the code in it gets run. I've put the exact same code in the TFSBuild.proj file, and it works fine. All the correct targets get over-written, etc. What's causing this?

Comment: This may be a stupid question but you placed that file in the right location on the **build server** right? Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi

Comment: Yeah, it's on the build server and is definately being parsed, as breaking the syntax by removing a > causes errors.

Comment: Why is a year and a half old question having its spelling corrected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember evaluation priority; If an item or property is set then it won't be overwritten in a latter include except where you call CreateProperty or CreateItem tasks. I found that this stopped me from running conditional tasks.

Set verbosity to 'diag' to see what gets evaluated on the server build when including.

Comment: My bad, i meant to put Custom.After.Microsoft.Common.Targets (which I've now corrected), so the evaluation order shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it actually did turn out to be the evaluation order, but not how we expected. The property group for DropBuildDependsOn was extended by us, but was then overridden later on by the TeamFoundation targets file. WE instead modified this file to import our project as well and it now all works.

Comment: You should place your overrides after the Import statement for the TF targets file.